# Some questions regarding a famous example of Sierpinski's.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

As is well known that, assuming the Continuum Hypothesis, there is a set $\mathcal  S$$\subset$$\mathscr R^2$ such that $\mathcal S$ is countable on every horizontal line and co-countable on every vertical line.  Consider also the relative complement of $\mathcal S$, $\mathcal S^{'}$=$\mathscr R^2$$\setminus$$\mathcal S$.  Since it is known that $\mathcal S$ is nonmeasurable, is $\mathcal S^{'}$ nonmeasurable as well?  Also are the following correct:

|$\mathcal S$|=|$\mathcal S^{'}$|=$\mathfrak c$?

Furthermore, for $\mathcal S^{'}$$\subset$$\mathscr R^2$, is $\mathcal S^{'}$ countable on every vertical line and co-countable on every horizontal line?

Apologies in advance for the triviality (and\or stupidity) of these questions (in case any of these assertions turn out be false).

Thanks in advance for your tolerance.

Comment: Thank you both, David and Asaf, for providing such helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $S$ could be defined so as to include the diagonal or not. To settle that: Say $\le$ is a well-ordering of $\Bbb R$ such that every real has at most countably many predecessors (and note of course that this has nothing to do with the standard order, for example we haven't specified whether $2<3$ or $3<2$), and let $$S=\{(x,y)\,:\,x<y\}.$$ Instead of saying $S'$ is the complement of $S$, let's say $$S'=\{(x,y)\,:\,x>y\}.$$

So the sets $S$, $S'$ and $D$ form a partition of $\Bbb R^2$, where $D$ is the diagonal $x=y$. It's clear that $S\cup S'$ has cardinality $c$. But there is an obvious bijection between $S$ and $S'$, hence $S$ has cardinality $c$.

And yes to your other questions; $S'$ is the same as $S$ reflected in the diagonal (and my $S'$ is the same as your $S'$ modulo uninteresting details).

Comment: @DavidUllrich:  A couple of questions regarding the diagonal $D$.  Since it is the diagonal, it (I believe) is correct to infer |$D$|=$\mathfrak c$?  Also, Monroe Eskew, in a comment to me regarding my mathoverflow question "A question regarding the relation between Freiling's Axiom of Symmetry and real-valued measurable cardinals," states that "Usually we give one-dimensional objects measure zero in the plane."  Would that convention hold for $D$, or is $D$ nonmeasurable as well (one could use Asaf's argument to make a case for that).

Comment: Well $D$ certainly does have cardinality $c$; the map $x\mapsto (x,x)$ is a bijection from $\Bbb R$ onto $D$. I and I suspect Asaf have been assuming that by "measurable" you meant "Lebesgue measurable". The set $D$ certainly _is_ Lebesgue measurable, and certainly _does_ have Lebesgue measure zero. You ask about whether some convention about what measure we "give" the diagonal would apply - that's undefined and/or up to you, if we're talking about some other sigma-algebra and some other measure then whether $D$ is measurable would depend on whether $D$ is measurable.

Comment: @DavidUllrich:  Your comment is very helpful.  Thanks.  It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since the measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra, they are closed under complements, yes. If $X\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is non-measurable, then $\Bbb R^n\setminus X$ is also non-measurable.

Moreover, every countable set is in fact measurable. Since we assume the continuum hypothesis, it follows that every non-measurable set has size $\aleph_1=2^{\aleph_0}=\frak c$. In particular $\Bbb R^2\setminus S$ and $S$.