# On Sierpinski's example of a set intersects every horizontal or vertical line in exactly one point

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Using the continuum hypothesis, one can prove that there exists
> a Lebesgue non-measurable subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $E$ intersects every horizontal or vertical line in exactly one point. (a) Use this set to show that there exists a function $f : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is Borel measurable in each variable separately, yet f is not Lebesgue measurable. (b) Show that the restriction of $f$ to any horizontal or vertical line has only one point of discontinuity.

The first sentence of the exercise is explained in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438642/some-questions-regarding-a-famous-example-of-sierpinskis), even though not an explicit construction of the set is shown. Still couldn't solve the exercise with reading the mentioned OP and the answers there. Please help, thanks!

Comment: The linked question talks about another set in $\Bbb R^2$ constructed by Sierpiński, not a set as you mean. Cannot you just assume the existence of $E$ and do $a)$ and $b)$ based off that existence? You don't need a construction of $E$ itself.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I tried for both (a) and (b) but I have no idea how to start at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $E \subseteq \Bbb R^2$ consider $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x,y)=1$ if $(x,y) \in E$ and $0$ otherwise. $f$ is not measurable as $E$ is not.

But if we fix the first coordinate to $x_0 \in \Bbb R^2$, the one-variable functon $f(x_0, \cdot)$ assumes the value $1$ only once, so that function is almost $0$ and thus measurable, quite trivially. The same for $f(\cdot, y_0)$ for any fixed $y_0 \in \Bbb R$. So that takes care of $a)$ and $b)$ both.